# "Power of" Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition

I was working on the following question for homework:

"Find an element x ∈ Z7 such that every nonzero element of Z7 is a power of x."

What does "power of" actually mean?

My initial understanding was that every non-zero element (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) were a power of x, i.e., x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6 where x equals each non-zero element. I now know this is wrong, but I thought that every non-zero element was literally a power of x. This is also how Britannica defines.

"power of 10, in mathematics, any of the whole-valued (integer) exponents of the number 10."

I have now come to realise that "power of" means "the number produced as a result of the base being multiplied a number of times, equal to the exponent." Can someone confirm whether this is correct or not?

Can someone also explain the question that I was doing for homework so that I can have another perspective regarding it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If we look at the powers of $6$ we have $6^1 = 6$, and then $6^2 = 1$ in the context of $\Bbb Z_7$ (*note that $6^2 = 36 = 35+1 = 7\cdot 5 + 1$*), and then this repeats... $6^3 = 6,~ 6^4 = 1,~6^5=6,\dots$.  In particular, you never have some value of $n$ such that $6^n = 3$ for instance so $6$ does not work for the choice of $x$ here.

Comment: For a simpler example, look at $\mathbb Z_3$.  Consider the residue $2$.  We see that $2^1\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, of course.  And $2^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  So $2$ would be a solution to your problem in that case.  Now try $p=5$ and then $p=7$.

Comment: We are looking for a single value of $x$ such that among $x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6$ we have each of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ appearing after evaluating.  I.e. we are looking for a generator of the multiplicative subgroup of $\Bbb Z_7^\times$.  What value is $2^1$?  How about $2^2$?  $2^3$? $2^4$?  (*Again, all of this in the context of $\Bbb Z_7$*)  Did we start looping again?  Does $2$ work for our purposes?  How about a different value?  There are only so many to check here.

Comment: "Power of": We have a group $(G,\cdot)$ and for $x\in G$ we write $x^0=e$ where $e$ is the neutral element, $x^k = x\cdot x\dots \cdot x$, $k$ times  and $x^{-k} = x^{-1} \cdot x^{-1}\cdot \dots \cdot x^{-1}$, $k$ times when $k$ is a positive integer and $x^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $x$. As somebody already mentioned you are interested in a generating element of the group, which in this context is also known as a "primitive root".

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The example of $10^2$... we say that $100$ is a power of ten.  We say that $2$ is the power *to which ten is taken*, we say that $2$ is the exponent in $10^2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you endlessly. Exactly what I needed.